# Is there a way to control the Python decimal quantize method when applied to zero?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding, zero

Consider the following Python3 snippet: (Python 3.7.7 on mac os catalina)

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as d
>>> zero = d('0')
>>> one = d('1')
>>> for q in range(10):
...   one.quantize(d('10') ** -q)
... 
Decimal('1')
Decimal('1.0')
Decimal('1.00')
Decimal('1.000')
Decimal('1.0000')
Decimal('1.00000')
Decimal('1.000000')
Decimal('1.0000000')
Decimal('1.00000000')
Decimal('1.000000000')

>>> for q in range(10):
...   zero.quantize(d('10') ** -q)
... 
Decimal('0')
Decimal('0.0')
Decimal('0.00')
Decimal('0.000')
Decimal('0.0000')
Decimal('0.00000')
Decimal('0.000000')
Decimal('0E-7')
Decimal('0E-8')
Decimal('0E-9')
```

Why does quantize with zero change to E notation at this point?  Why is it inconsistent with other numbers?  And how can I control it?

Note: I get exactly the same inconsistency if I use use the built-in `round` function instead of `quantize`, which leads me to guess that `round` calls `quantize` when it gets a Decimal.

Since I want strings with trailing zeros, the best workaround I can think of is to write my own `_round()` function:

```
def _round(s, n):
    if decimal.Decimal(s).is_zero():
        return '0.' + '0' * n
    return decimal.Decimal(s).quantize(decimal.Decimal(10) ** -n)
```

but that seems a bit lame.  And anyway I'd like to understand *why* `Decimal.quantize` behaves like this.

Comment: I don't think this is only limited to `quantize` method, rather it's how `__str__` method is defined. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_pydecimal.py).

Comment: Don't confuse a `Decimal` object with its string representation. This question has nothing particularly to do with `quantize` or `round`. If you simply enter `Decimal('0.0000000')` at a prompt, you'll see the same output from the REPL: `Decimal('0E-7')`. You want to look into string formatting.

Comment: @ywbaek  thanks - I shall look at the string formatting. And perhaps update the question to ask how to control that ...

Comment: `format(my_decimal_object, 'f')` may be all you need (following the `quantize` option). Or perhaps use an explicit precision, e.g., `format(my_decimal_object, '.9f')` , and then there's no need for `round` or `quantize`.

Comment: @markdickinson yes - that was the conclusion I came to.  The inconsistency (apparently) arises from the attempt to get rid of leading zeros in Decimal.__new__() where is says `self._int = str(int(intpart+fracpart))` -- I think this would be better written as `self._int = str(int(intpart))+fracpart` but there may be some other implications of this change that I cannot see.

Comment: No, the code is right. While trailing zeros are significant for `Decimal`, leading zeros are not: there's no difference between `Decimal("000E-6")` and `Decimal("0E-6")`. None of this is accidental: there's a carefully designed [specification](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html) that the `decimal` module follows.

Comment: Apologies for the extended comment discussion, @MarkDickinson,  but when both intpart and fracpart are all zeros (as in my case) then the code as is, destroys the trailing zeros.  Which it should not do?

Comment: It destroy _leading_ zeros, not _trailing_ zeros - it keeps track of the exponent. The code is correct (and very well tested :-)  ).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, leaving aside *why* Python3 `Decimal` has this behaviour, the way to control the format is not to mess with `quantize` at all.  It is much simpler and more consistent to use `format`, like so:  (with the same definitions of `zero` and `one` as Decimals)

```
>>> for q in range(10):
...   '{:.{n}f}'.format(zero, n=q)
... 
'0'
'0.0'
'0.00'
'0.000'
'0.0000'
'0.00000'
'0.000000'
'0.0000000'
'0.00000000'
'0.000000000'
>>> for q in range(10):
...   '{:.{n}f}'.format(one, n=q)
... 
'1'
'1.0'
'1.00'
'1.000'
'1.0000'
'1.00000'
'1.000000'
'1.0000000'
'1.00000000'
'1.000000000'
```

With thanks to the commentary for useful pointers.